# Can't add more than one row in Listview at a Fragment

Tags: android, json, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment with data from JSON. When I click on a list item, the data is sent to a Fragment (DetalhesFragment.java). If the user confirms the data, it will hit a button in DetalhesFragment to send those information to another list on the right of the main activity (PedidosFragment.java).

It's working! The data from the middle Fragment appears on the first row of the listview on PedidosFragment. But, if I try to choose another item to send there, the row is overwrited with the new data..isn't adding a row under the first row.

Can you help me, guys? Here, the codes..

DetalhesFragment.java

```
package com.example.waitersoriginal;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetalhesFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    TextView nomeEntrada,descrEntrada,valorEntrada,nmArm,dsArm,vlArm;
    String txtNome, txtDescr;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalhes_fragment, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        nomeEntrada= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        descrEntrada= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        valorEntrada= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button1:

                        PedidosFragment array = (PedidosFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3); 
                        array.criaArray(txtNome,txtDescr);

                        break;
                 }
            }
        }
            );
        return view;
    }    

    public void change(String txt, String txt1){
        nomeEntrada.setText(txt);
        descrEntrada.setText(txt1);
        txtNome = txt;
        txtDescr = txt1;
        //valorEntrada.setText(txt2);

    }  

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }    
}
```

PedidosFragment.java

```
package com.example.waitersoriginal;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class PedidosFragment extends ListFragment{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaPedidos;

    private static final String TAG_NM = "NOME";
    private static final String TAG_DS = "DESCR";

    public PedidosFragment(){}

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
      return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedidos_fragment, container, false); 
    }

    void criaArray(String nomeProd, String descrProd) {

        listaPedidos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listaPedidos,
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_NM, TAG_DS}, 
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.pid});

        setListAdapter(adapter2);

        map3.put(TAG_NM, nomeProd);
        map3.put(TAG_DS, descrProd);

        listaPedidos.add(map3);    

            ((BaseAdapter) adapter2).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
}
```

Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you are overriding you adapter and creating a new one each time, with the newest item.

try with this (assuming both fragments are in memory) :

```
public class PedidosFragment extends ListFragment{

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listaPedidos;

    private static final String TAG_NM = "NOME";
    private static final String TAG_DS = "DESCR";



    public PedidosFragment(){}

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 

         listaPedidos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listaPedidos,
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_NM, TAG_DS}, 
                new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.pid});

         setListAdapter(adapter2);


         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pedidos_fragment, container, false); 
    }

    void criaArray(String nomeProd, String descrProd) {

        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3.put(TAG_NM, nomeProd);
        map3.put(TAG_DS, descrProd);

        listaPedidos.add(map3);    

        ((BaseAdapter) adapter2).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
}
```

Also, avoid using `constructors` with `fragments`, instead use `Bundles`

Hope this helps